# How to jump to a specific customer name in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I am trying to create a Google Sheet that lists all payments made for tuition by family. I would like to use only one tab (not create a tab for each family) as I have about 120 families to keep track of.

Any thoughts of the best way to do this without having to scroll forever to get to the specific family I need to look at? Currently I have the families listed in alphabetical order in multiples of 4 going down and then the next set of 4, etc. This is easier when it comes to printing certain sections of the sheet for cross reference (i.e. not having to scroll down forever to find a name).

```
Date     Family
         **Penland**
8/6/20    $150 cc = app fee
8/17/20   $550 ck #2635 = reg, corp
9/10/20   $650 ck #3016 = Aug tuit
10/12/20  $650 ck #4361 = Oct tuit
11/10/20  $650 ck #3027 = Nov tuit
12/16/20  $650 ck #2143 = Dec tuit
1/20/21   $650 ck #2738 = Jan tuit
2/26/21   $650 ck #4622 = Feb tuit
```

I know how to use the F5 shortcut to get to a specific cell but how do you get to a specific cell by typing in the name of the family? That would help with the whole scrolling issue.

Or if anyone has a better idea of how to record these payments I'd love your help.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Find** feature. Press <kbd>Control + F</kbd> and type a family name to jump to a row that contains that family name.

Comment: doubleunary.....you are my new favorite person!!!!! thank you so so much.